# String Array to 2D String array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a String Array, map[] which looks like...

"####"

"#GB#"

"#BB#"

"####"

So map[1] = "#GB#"

How do I turn this into a 2D array so that newMap[1][1] would give me "G"?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you really need a 2D array, or will `map[1].charAt(1)` suffice?

Comment: Definetely needs to be a 2D array unfortunatly.

Comment: Do you need Strings[][], or char[][] will also do the trick?

Comment: Well it's in a String, but a char[][] would be better, I just don't know how to

Answer (score 3):

If you really need it, you can use [`String.toCharArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) on each element array to convert them into an array.

```
String[] origArr = new String[10];


char[][] charArr = new char[10][];

for(int i = 0; i< origArr.length;i++)
    charArr[i] = origArr[i].toCharArray();
```

If you want to break it up into `String[]` instead, you could use (thanks Pshemo)

```
String[] abc = "abc".split("(?!^)"); //-> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't be dynamic. It will take O(n) + m to get to a character of a string. A much faster and dynamic approach would be a Hashmap where the key is the String and the value is a char array. Kind of unnecessarily complex but you get the seeking and individual letter charAts without having to go through the cumbersome process of resizing a primitive array.